# Project Euler, Problem 8: Why is my code wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I have been trying to solve [problem 8 in Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8). Finally thought that I finished my code. But I am getting the wrong answer. Can someone explain why it is wrong ?

```python
n = """
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
"""
n = n.strip().split('\n')
n = ''.join(n)
k = []
l = 1
f = []

for i in range(0,988):
    k.append(n[i:i+13])

for m in k:
    for z in m:
        l *= int(z)
        f.append(l)

print(max(f))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compute the product of every sequence of 13 digits. Everything looks okay, but in the loop over `k`, you need to set `l` back to 1 each time. Otherwise you just continue multiplying each digit by the running product... so you get a very big number.

In other words, change your last loop to this:

```
for m in k:
    l = 1
    for z in m:
        l *= int(z)
        f.append(l)
```